# push local branch to bitbucket and then pull it to server

Tags: git, github, git-branch, git-pull

Just got known with branches. I got a problem:
I'm at master on local machine. I do

```
git checkout "commit_hash"
```

After this a make a branch

```
git branch "new_branch_name"
```

Now i want to push it to Bitbucket, and then i want to pull same stuff to my server repository, and to not damage the master branch during this process.
Please help me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
git push --set-upstream origin new_branch_name
 # or, shorter:
git push -u origin new_branch_name
```

This will push the branch and set it so it will always be pushed to the same branch on origin.

on the server:

```
git fetch origin new_branch_name
git checkout new_branch_name
```